# paypal donation button integration in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

it is required to integrate the paypal donation button in asp.net c# web form, on clicking the donate button an email should be sent to the receiver with capturing the details of the donor like donor name, occupation, address and donation amount etc.

Please any help from anyone will be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for asp.net page for a simple donation button

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="myemail">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Item name">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Item ID">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="12.00">
<input type="hidden" name="buyer_credit_promo_code" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="buyer_credit_product_category" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="buyer_credit_shipping_method" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="buyer_credit_user_address_change" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input name="cbt" value="Click here to confirm the payment" type="hidden"/>
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">

<input name="CANCELURL" value='<%=errorurl %>' type="hidden"/>
<input name="return" value='<%=url %>' type="hidden"/>

<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

'errorurl' and return url 'url' can be defined from codeback.

Also you can avoid unwanted parameters from the code.

You can set a custom image in the 'img' tag of the code.

Create a button of your own by using this link

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donate-intro-outside

Answer (score 0):

First u go through with Paypal Documentaion... It is best source for to learn all the things which u require.

[Paypal SDK Documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks)

[DOnation of paypal using Asp.Net : Custom Control](http://documentation.spicelogic.com/docs/ASP-NET-PayPal-Control/Donation-Button-13)

[How to Use Paypal SDK.. Sample applicaiton.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/UsePayPalPaymentInASPNET.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Resources mentioned are pretty good. To go through a live-setup example, you can visit this [LINK](http://www.codersbarn.com/?tag=/paypal) and learn how you can achieve the same on your website.

NOTE: PayPal is integrated within a website, and doesn't offer a one-click solution like Web-API.